# Calculate mean and variance of a distribution of a distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, hierarchical-bayesian

I am using hierarchical distributions, of the following form:

$\theta\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$

$\mu\sim N(a,b)$

I can calculate the mean, and variance using Mathematica, and find:

$\mathrm{E}(\theta)=a$

$var(\theta)=b^2 + \sigma^2$

However, I would like to know how I could go about doing this with pen and paper. Is there a simpler way than working out the pdf for $\theta$?

Another example, that is similar in nature, that Mathematica is struggling with is:

$\theta\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$

$\mu\sim t-student(\nu,a,b)$

Similarly, does anyone have a methodology for dealing with these type 'distribution of distribution' settings? Additionally could someone tell me the name of this type of probability theory?

Best,

Ben

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expectation and variance computations in your example can be handled with the *law of total expectation* and *law of total variance*.

The [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) in your case reads:

$$ E(\theta) = E_{\mu} ( E_{\theta} (\theta \mid \mu ) ) $$

where the subscripts indicate which variable is being averaged over in the expectation.  The inside expectation is

$$ E_{\theta} ( \theta \mid \mu ) = \mu $$

and so the law gives the total expectation as

$$ E(\theta) = E_{\mu} ( \mu ) = a $$

The [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) in your case reads

$$ var (\theta) = E_{\mu}( var_{\theta} (\theta \mid \mu ) ) + var_{\mu} ( E_{\theta} ( \theta \mid \mu ) ) $$

where, again, the subscripts are telling us what is being averaged over.

We can calculate the first term as

$$ E_{\mu}( var_{\theta} (\theta \mid \mu ) ) = E_{\mu}( \sigma^2 ) = \sigma^2 $$

and the second as

$$ var_{\mu} ( E_{\theta} ( \theta \mid \mu ) ) =  var_{\mu} ( \mu ) = b^2 $$

which recovers your result from mathematica.

Comment: Many thanks - I hadn't thought to use those! Best, Ben